# tkinter show Frames depending on variable value

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been attempting to do some python code where I want a different frame to "lift" to the top depending upon the value of a variable. I have the variable etc all working ok, and can lift a frame by writing `[framename].lift()`, however when I try and make the frame dynamic it won't work.

The error that I am getting back is 'str' object has no attribute. I get that it is seeing my dynamic text as a string rather than a command, but am completely out of ideas as to how to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

here is the code

```
class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p0 = Page0(self)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        p0.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        pt = "P"+str(seq)
        pt.show()
```

and here is the fault

```
File "C:/Users/gaming/Documents/MP/MP_SCL.py", line 66, in __init__
pt.show()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pt = "P"+str(seq)` so `pt` is a string and therefore has no attribute 'show'.

I guess that you would like to call the `show` method of objects called something like `P0`, `P1`, ...

To do so, you can create a dictionary: `P = {'P0': P0, ...}`,
so that you can do 
`pt = P["P"+str(seq)]` to retrieve the object. And then, `pt.show()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself creating multiple variables whose names are different only by a number, that's a sign that you should be using a different data structure.

If you want to be able to access the frames by their number, store them in a list or dictionary.

For example:

```
p = {
    0: Page0(self),
    1: Page1(self),
    2: Page2(self),
    3: Page3(self),
}
...
p[0].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
p[1].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
...
p[0].show()
```